# How I can Enable href for toggle

Tags: jquery, toggle, font-awesome, href

My menu toggle is working only with font awesome's icon but I want toggle with href and icon both, this time toggle is working with icon only

```js
$("ul.product-categories li.hassub a").after('<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>');
$("ul li.hassub i").click(function() {
  $(this).next().slideToggle();
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  $(this).parent().toggleClass("active");
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="widget-title">Categories</h3>
<ul class="product-categories">
  <li><a href="#" title="Men">Men</a>
    <ul class="children">
      <li><a href="#" title="Bag & Luggage">Bag & Luggage</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="Eyewear">Eyewear</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="Jewelry">Jewelry</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="Shoes">Shoes</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="Skyrts">Skyrts</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" title="woment">woment</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" title="Bag">Bag</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="Bed & Bath">Bed & Bath</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="Sport tops & Vest">Sport tops & Vest</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="Sport undewear">Sport undewear</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" title="kids">kids</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" title="All Product">All Product</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what is you need for href?

Comment: simply change your js code `$("ul li.hassub i").click(function() {` to `$("ul li.hassub a, ul li.hassub i").click(function() {`.

it maybe work

Comment: Sorry No luck: this is my link Left side Categories: https://raheela.sialkotwebmedia.com/product/safety-gloves/hoodies

Answer (score 0):

**i have fix the issue with this double Function:**

```js
 $("ul.product-categories li.hassub a").after('<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>');
        $("ul li.hassub a").click(function(){
      $(this).next().next().slideToggle();   
      $(this).next().toggleClass("active");   
      $(this).next().parent().toggleClass("active");   
         
        })
     $("ul li.hassub i").click(function(){
      $(this).next().slideToggle();
      $(this).toggleClass("active");
      $(this).parent().toggleClass("active");
     });
```